# I can't find dofollow or nofollow in my blog

Tags: nofollow, dofollow

I have [a blog](http://www.mycsnippets.blogspot.com/) which I want to make do-follow but I am unable to find any place to change nofollow to dofollow please help me the html code is [here](http://www.ideone.com/mmang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @tamdamson said, I also think you can't get deep enough to change that.

If you pay attention to the code you posted, will notice that it isn't HTML+CSS. It is a XSLT stylesheet, ie, a XML document.

The advantage of using that kind of document is: you can declare repetition rules, and wrap snippets (templates) into other files.

Can you find even the blog post code in the code you sent? No. You find a call to a widget (a file with rules for processing blog posts). You can change it going into Design mode and editing the blog posts widget.

Comments are another widget called inside blog posts. But you don't have access to this one AFAIK. Thus you can't change the nofollow to follow.

Comment: @fahad - sorry for not really solving your problem, but I'm glad you are clarified about that now. Yw.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Blogspot/Blogger, so you won't be able to get deep enough into the code to change it. Links are probably stripped down by the server, like most blog software will do. Writing a Javascript function to strip out nofollow attributes after the page loads would be easy, but pointless since searchbots won't notice.

Comment: yes it is a blogspot.There used to be a expression 'nofollow' which should be changed to 'dofollow'but I dont find it in my html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your website HTML source. Unfortunately, there is no `rel="nofollow"` or `rel="follow"` attribute. So, by whatever method you use, you will not find it.